# How to create DateTimeformatter with optional seconds arguments

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing

I am trying to create a `DateTimeformatter` to validate following date times:

```
String date1 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28";
String date2 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.1";
String date3 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.12";
String date4 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.123";
String date5 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.1234";
String date6 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.12345";
String date7 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.123456";
String date8 = "2017-07-06T17:25:28.";
```

I have tried the following date time formatter to validate above dates:

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                   .appendPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN)
                                   .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
                                   .toFormatter();
```

It works fine for all the above dates, but according to my requirement it should fail with `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` for `date8`.

Note: I am aware that I can achieve expected result with following formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter
                       .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSS][.SSSSS][.SSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S]");
```

But I wanted to know that can we achieve expected result by changing in `formatter1`?

For parsing the date I am using following:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(date1, formatter1);
```

Comment: What are DATE_TIME_FORMATTER and DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN ?

Comment: @PallaviSonal: thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: @AmitGarg Why did you unnaccept my answer? Is that any case that failed and I missed?

Comment: @Hugo; Thanks for your help. It is working fine, nothing wrong in your answer. As I have written this question just to learn about DateTimeFormatter, I am Just want to find more and more different answer on this question. I have noticed that I lot of time answer accepted questions are not seen by a lot of developer. This might be my personal experience. I will accept you answer tomorrow (Just waiting for some more different solutions) :)

Comment: @AmitGarg Ok, got it! I thought that I had made some mistake... You're right, many people don't look at accepted questions. Thanks for clarifying it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must create an optional section (using `optionalStart()` and `optionalEnd()` methods) containing the decimal point followed by 1 to 6 digits:

```
String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN)
    // optional decimal point followed by 1 to 6 digits
    .optionalStart()
    .appendPattern(".")
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 1, 6, false)
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
```

This parses from `date1` to `date7` and throws a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` with `date8`.

---

This also works the same way:

```
String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN)
    // optional decimal point followed by 1 to 6 digits
    .optionalStart()
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 1, 6, true)
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
```

Comment: `.appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)` has always worked for me. Because if the minimum is `0`, it basically becomes optional...

Answer (score -2):

Try set `minWidth` to 1, i.e. `.appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 1, 6, true)`.

Comment: Then it will also fail for `"2017-07-06T17:25:28"` that OP wants to be parsed