# Java: DateTimeFormatter parse milliseconds timestamp with different number of digits

Tags: java, datetime-format

I have the following `DateTimeFormatter` code

```
DateTimeFormatter sysDateFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

And an example of the timestamp would be `2018-09-04 09:16:11.305`. The milliseconds have 3 digits. And the following code to parse the timestamp would just work fine.

```
LocalTime.parse("2018-09-04 09:16:11.305", sysDateFmt)
```

However, sometimes the millisecond part of the timestamp I encountered only have 2 digits, i.e. `2018-09-12 17:33:30.42`. Then this is where I come across the error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-09-12 17:33:30.42' could not be parsed at index 20
```

What is the efficient solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: You might to need to use a more lenient approach - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962417/lenient-java-8-date-parsing)

Comment: [Maybe this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950633/how-to-create-datetimeformatter-with-optional-seconds-arguments)

Comment: Should the time be equivalent to 2018-09-12 17:33:30.420 or 2018-09-12 17:33:30.042?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the length of date

```
    String a = "2018-09-04 09:16:11.305"; //length = 23
    String b = "2018-09-04 09:16:11.30";  //length = 22
```

then

```
    String date = null;
    DateTimeFormatter sysDateFmt23 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    DateTimeFormatter sysDateFmt22 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");

    if (date.length() == 23){
        LocalTime.parse(date, sysDateFmt23);
    } else if (date.length() == 22){
        LocalTime.parse(date, sysDateFmt22);
    }
```